# Use pcasys program from NBIS package for classification of fingerprint

Tags: fingerprint

I am working on my app which will be a client-server based application. Login will be based on fingerprints.
On server side, I am using NBIS software.
I just want to run classification of fingerprint. For that purpose I chose pcasys program.

I need to exec program *pcasys* with myparmfile

```
pcasys my.prs
```

my.prs include same parameters like basic prs file for pcasys.

I just specified path to my list of fingerprints.

```
demo_images_list pcasys/all.txt
```

When I exec this program, I will get this error:

```
 ERROR : extractfet_ret : feature FING_CLASS not found
```

I know there is missing FING_CLASS flag in the image file. I think this flag will set pcasys into this file not me. I need it for automatic classification. So question is there:

**Can I use pcasys for my fingerprints, or is it just a demo which is working with default data from test direcotry?**

Comment: did you solve this? I'm facing a similar issue, will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because `pcasys` expect to find `FING_CLASS` header in your wsq image.

The `FING_CLASS` header is the actual class of the image which should be one of the following `A L R S T W`

The value is not really nessesery since from the code it is only used for sorting

> find out
> from its header what its actual class is (to be used later for
> scoring)

After all `pcasys` will generate it correct class after it has finished running

You can use `rdwsqcom` to read the headers, `dlwsqcom` to delete the headers and `wrwsqcom` to write new headers